# UsernameTokenValidator Can not @Autowired Dao

Tags: spring, web-services, hibernate, autowired, spring-ws

I have a Spring-ws and i am using Apahce-wss4j for spring-ws authentication. I want to use my Dao class in my custom TokenValidator class. But there was an exception can not @Autowired my Dao class. Here is my code

applicationContext.xml

> `<bean id="myWssConfig" class="tr.com.xxx.services.MyWssConfig"/>
>       <bean id="kepDBDAO" class="tr.com.xxx.dao.KepDBDAOImpl"/>
>       <bean id="ssha" class="tr.com.xxx.utils.SSHA"/>
>       <bean id="memberStatusService" class="tr.com.xxx.services.MemberStatusServiceImpl"/>
>       <bean id="myUsernameTokenValidator" class="tr.com.xxx.services.MyUsernameTokenValidator">
>           <property name="kepDBDAO" ref="kepDBDAO"/>
>       </bean>`

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
        <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken"/>
        <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="callbackHandler"/>
        <property name="wssConfig">
            <ref bean="myWssConfig"/>
        </property>
    </bean>
</sws:interceptors>
```

Here is MyWssConfig.java

```
@Component("myWssConfig")
public class MyWssConfig extends WSSConfig {

    public MyWssConfig() {
        setValidator(WSSecurityEngine.USERNAME_TOKEN, MyUsernameTokenValidator.class);
        setRequiredPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
    }
}
```

And here is MyUsernameTokenValidator.java

```
@Component
public class MyUsernameTokenValidator extends UsernameTokenValidator {


    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(MyUsernameTokenValidator.class);

    @Autowired
    private KepDBDAO kepDBDAO;

    @Transactional
    protected void verifyPlaintextPassword(UsernameToken usernameToken, RequestData data) throws WSSecurityException {
        if (usernameToken != null && usernameToken.getPassword() != null) {   

            byte[] saltValue = null;
            kepDBDAO.getWsUsers("basvuru");
            String hashPassword = null;
            try {
                hashPassword = SSHA.calculateSSHA256(saltValue, usernameToken.getPassword());
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.toString(), e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.toString(), e);
            }


            usernameToken.setPassword(hashPassword);


            super.verifyDigestPassword(usernameToken, data);
        }
    }

    public KepDBDAO getKepDBDAO() {
        return kepDBDAO;
    }

    public void setKepDBDAO(KepDBDAO kepDBDAO) {
        this.kepDBDAO = kepDBDAO;
    }
}
```

Couldn't @Autowired my KepDBDAO when I call webservice in SOAPUI.

Help me please.. THank you all guys.

Comment: I am assuming KepDBDAO is an interface and KepDBDAOImpl is marked as `@Service`. Is there any exception trace you can post?

Comment: Yes KepDBDAO is an interface and I can using and testing my KepDBDAO there was no problem. There wasn't exception :( i saw that debug mode... @NikhilTalreja

Comment: You said 'But there was an exception can not @Autowired my Dao class'. What was the exception trace here.

Comment: Sorry. There was no exception. I want to said my think. This problem was occur not Runtime. when i call my webservice this problem occur. This is '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">java.lang.NullPointerException</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'

Comment: How can you be sure without a stack trace that the `NullPointerException` is due to this and not something else

Comment: I see that kepDBDAO variable is null in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

1. In applicationContext:

<context:component-scan base-package="tr.com.xxx.dao"/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="package for MyUsernameTokenValidator"/>

remove these beans:

kepDBDAO, myUsernameTokenValidator

2. Remove setter and getter for KepDBDAO in MyUsernameTokenValidator 

3. Make sure KepDBDAOImpl is marked as @Service
```

Comment: I did your suggestions but doesn't work :( I think problem is MyUsernameTokenValidator.java maybe. Because i can be use KepDBDAO another modules

Comment: If `MyUsernameTokenValidator` is spring managed, It should not cause a problem

Comment: It is a Spring @Component

Comment: It also needs to be included in a package scan for it to be considered as a spring bean

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
@Component("myWssConfig")
public class MyWssConfig extends WSSConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MyUsernameTokenValidator myUsernameTokenValidator;

    //
    @PostConstruct
    public void myInit() {
        setValidator(WSSecurityEngine.USERNAME_TOKEN, myUsernameTokenValidator);
        setRequiredPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
    }
}
```

Comment: `org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSConfig`  is a final class and cannot be extended.